# python_2_unicode_compatible error

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, ubuntu, django-models

I've `models.py` as follows,

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.utils.timezone import now

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    class Meta:
            verbose_name = 'tag'
            verbose_name_plural = 'tags'
            ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
            return self.name
.............  and so on
```

When I ran `python manage.py syncdb` this is the error I got:

```
itman@itman:~/djangoApp/mysite$ python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 231, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 30, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 158, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 67, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 88, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/itman/djangoApp/mysite/bmark/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
ImportError: cannot import name python_2_unicode_compatible
```

I don't know why the module is not imported. I'm using Python 2.7 and Django 1.4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`python_2_unicode_compatible` feature has only been added in Django 1.5 version.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.encoding.python_2_unicode_compatible

Comment: Thanks mate! I did a django upgrade using the following:   sudo apt-get install python-setuptools ; 
sudo easy_install --upgrade django                                    and that solved the problem

Comment: This answer doesn't actually answer the question, and I'm getting the same error with django 1.3.  Upgrading to 1.6 breaks graphite, so . . . thanks but this really is not an answer.

Comment: ```$ python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
$ 1.6.5```
but i allso have ```cannot import name python_2_unicode_compatible```

Comment: This does not solve the problem... Check out @Desperad0 answer! It worked for me.

Answer (score 37):

For the latest Django 3.0.4 , and auditlog try

```
from six import python_2_unicode_compatible
```

instead of

```
from django.utils.six import python_2_unicode_compatible
```

if it is not install  run the below code

```
pip install six
```

Comment: Django 3 doesn't support python 2, what would you get out of using `python_2_unicode_compatible` anyways?

Comment: @goose how to make change in the package file? i.e python3.8/site-packages/django_messages/encoding?

Answer (score 16):

try

```
from django.utils.six import python_2_unicode_compatible
```

instead of

```
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
```

this works well for me in Django 1.10.6

Comment: works fine with django 2. Thanks for the suggestion. from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible this also works with django 2x

Comment: Django 3.0 changed to 'from six import python_2_unicode_compatible'

Comment: six  is not available in django 3.0.2, still facing the issue

Comment: @AbhishekSoni Django 3.0+ no longer supports Python 2 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/#removed-private-python-2-compatibility-apis) so you can probably just remove the imports and decorators from your code and run your app under Python 3.

Comment: from django.utils import six, timezone
ImportError: cannot import name 'six'

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same issue when I upgraded the **Django version 2.x to 3.x**.

This issue, I faced due to `auditlog` library.

**First, execute the below command**

```
pip uninstall auditlog
```

**then**

```
pip install auditlog3
```

Answer (score 6):

For me the issue was `django-jet` package which is not compatible with `django3` there is an [issue](https://github.com/geex-arts/django-jet/issues/487) on `django-jet` github apparently you need to use `django-3-jet` instead.

Comment: It seems that `django-jet` is no longer maintained so, for Django 3.0 or 4.0 I'm using `django-jet-reboot` instead.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue when I wanted to use Django for Graphite.
Turns out I had Django 1.3 installed and my Graphite version was breaking with Django > 1.5, so installing the latest version of the 1.4 branch fixed the problem:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade 'Django<1.5'
```

Comment: it is not solved: python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())" $ 1.6.5 but i allso have cannot import name python_2_unicode_compatible

Comment: This fixed my problem, Was also trying to install Graphite

Answer (score 3):

It's actually also present in the 1.4 series since 1.4.2. You should really be using the latest 1.4.X release (1.4.10 as of the time of this writing) as earlier versions have known security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a same error while i was using the Djnago-multiselect app
that was becuase the app was trying to run the following import

```
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
```

But in the newer version of django python_2_unicode_compatible is not in the encodings.py but rather in the six module and install if six is not there for you using

```
pip install six
```

and then go to the django.utils.encoding.py file
and simply import python_2_unicode_compatible from six like that

```
from six import python_2_unicode_compatible
```

Answer (score 1):

I have founded same problem :

```
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
ImportError: cannot import name 'python_2_unicode_compatible'
```

I have update python version to python3.8, and I worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is an existing package that supports Django 3:
[auditlog3](https://pypi.org/project/auditlog3/)

You can install it via `pip install auditlog3`

Answer (score 0):

I have this upgrading Django 1.9 (Python 2.7) to Django 3.2 (Python 3.9).

You can solve this with a bash one liner:

```
grep -ril "from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible"  your_project_source_code | xargs sed -i 's@from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible@from django.utils.six import python_2_unicode_compatible@g'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using Django in another computer, but wanted to copy the project with the virtual environment, too. It didn't work, so I had to recreate the environment.
I got this error because I missed out one package from many:

```
django-background-tasks
```

So I had to install this package, and it solved the error.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Install six by command: `pip install six`

Step 2: Go to the file: `your_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py`

Step 3: Add this line to your file: `from six import python_2_unicode_compatible`

Answer (score 0):

for me replacing
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
with
from django.utils.six import python_2_unicode_compatible
with installing below library works!
pip install django-utils-six