# Python manage.py runserver doesn't work on a project (Django)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, powershell, server

So I made my own project it worked with `python manage.py runserver` but when I tried with a new project, it's a challenge project and the challenge is to improve the django app. I use Python 3.8.1 (64-bit) and when I write `python manage.py runserver` on Admin Powershell it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thatp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\thatp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\thatp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\thatp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\thatp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\thatp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\thatp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\thatp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\thatp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\thatp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\thatp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\djangoProjects\django-challenge-master\app\mailer\models.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
ImportError: cannot import name 'python_2_unicode_compatible' from 'django.utils.encoding' (C:\Users\thatp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py)
```

So if someone could help me that would be awesome.

Comment: @ **Mikael Kolehmainen**, what is your django version? To know the version use:  >>> import django
>>> django.VERSION

Comment: I am using django version 3.0.2

Comment: @ **Mikael Kolehmainen** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741754/python-2-unicode-compatible-error,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error are in your model, see bellow:

```
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
ImportError: cannot import name 'python_2_unicode_compatible' from 'django.utils.encoding' (C:\Users\thatp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py
```

it only work on Django>=1.5, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20741848/9710734

Comment: Yeah I found a file where it said which version I should use it said Django==1.8.6.