# ImportError: cannot import name 'python_2_unicode_compatible' from 'django.utils.encoding'

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, importerror

I was trying to run-server and I got this error.
I was building an app for inventory management [this is the screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIqR3.png)

python version 3.8.1
django version 3.0.4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python\_2\_unicode\_compatible error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741754/python-2-unicode-compatible-error)

Comment: does @DARK_C0D3R answer work?