# how to successfully start the server in django?

Tags: python, django, debugging, django-rest-framework, django-runserver

Whenever I put the command `python manage.py runserver` and it throws an error.

```
    from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
ImportError: cannot import name 'python_2_unicode_compatible' from 'django.utils.encoding' (C:\JavaScript\DR_BRO\backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py)
```

I was trying to run the server in Django. But it's thorough an error like

```
    from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
ImportError: cannot import name 'python_2_unicode_compatible' from 'django.utils.encoding' (C:\JavaScript\DR_BRO\backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py)
```

Comment: I think you are running django on python 2 old version

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741754/python-2-unicode-compatible-error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python\_2\_unicode\_compatible error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741754/python-2-unicode-compatible-error)